# same task in different Project boards in Azure devops

Tags: azure-devops

Several Projects with their boards are created in Azure (For example A and B).
But we have lots of work items that should be in both A and B Project boards.
Every time I make a copy of it and move to the other Projects board. But whatever I change for example in A board it does not have impact in B board.

Is there any way that the work items will be connected and have impact on each other?

I have tried the area option but nothing happened.

Comment: I don't think a work item should ever be in two projects at the same time.  Your structure is wrong if you have things that are in both.  Either split it into one work item per project for the work that is being assigned to each team, or pick the project where the responsibility lies for the specific task.

Comment: Dear JeffUkThank you for response

Comment: One project is for PMs the other for Development,
so the bug or product backlog item is opened in my board and afterwards when the developer starts working on it I should copy the task or bug in their board, and while making any changes in the content or attaching some files, I should do it twice
thus I want to find a way that task is opened in one place and edited in one place.
Is there any interconnections between the projects?

Comment: Can't you just have one work item and use assignments to assign it to the relevant person?  Having a 'PM Project' and a 'Development Project' seems odd.

Comment: Assignment for persons works, but what if the A-team do the developers job, but the tester is in B-team, because only he can test it, not the A-teams testers. The WI stays on the A-team board and the B-team, including tester, can't see this WI in their board - which is a problem in my case.